# mismatched input ';' expecting <EOF>(line 1, pos 90)

Tags: apache-spark-sql, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to fetch multiple rows in zeppelin using spark SQL.

Here's my SQL statement:

```
select id, name from target where updated_at = "val1", "val2","val3"
```

This is the error message I'm getting:

> mismatched input ';' expecting < EOF >(line 1, pos 90)

Comment: did you try adding a semi-colon to the end of the statement? e.g.: `%sql select id, name from target where updated_at = "val1", "val2","val3";`

Comment: Zeppelin doesn't accepts semicolon `;` as a terminator, it adds the terminator while processing itself.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your exact requirement is but your match condition doesn't conform to SQL syntax standards. Below statement will work if your requirement does match this:

`select id, name from target where updated_at in ('val1', 'val2','val3')`

Comment: @AnkitaWankhede, could you please accept the answer if it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

In case someone gets this error in the `selectExpr` function from Spark like me: the correct usage of `selectExpr` is not a string which contains a comma separated list of column names, but a list of column names:

```
spark_df.selectExpr("id, name")  # ouch, wrong
> mismatched input ';' expecting <EOF>(line 1, pos xy)

spark_df.selectExpr("id", "name")     # right!
> DataFrame[..]

spark_df.selectExpr(*["id", "name"])  # correct too!
> DataFrame[..]
```